# Shutdown in BAT - Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I have this .bat file here which kills everything and then shutdown the computer. The problem is that this shutdown command is not working ... amd I doing something wrong? I'm killing everything before shutting down because this way the shutdown is faster, thanks!

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME eq %userdomain%\%username%" /FI "STATUS eq running"') do (
    if not "%%i"=="svchost.exe" (
        if not "%%i"=="explorer.exe" (
            if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
                if not "%%i"=="tasklist.exe" (
                    echo.
                    Taskkill /f /im "%%i" 
                    echo.
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

shutdown /s /f /t 00
```

Comment: Well, why are you using shutdown.exe? Its a long time ago, but i remember a direct shutdown command in batch, or is it calling the same? Any way, you should try the shutdown command without killing all tasks, if it works then, u got ur answer.

Comment: Already tried without the .exe, it's the same thing ... nothing happens :-(

Comment: Try the second thing i wrote.

Comment: `shutdown /p /f` also looks nice

Comment: @Luftbaum it goes in a loop, it only works if I type it manually on prompt, on bat file, it goes in an infinite loop executing this command non-stop

Comment: Sorry I have to go in bed now, but I would Google for a good way to use shutdown command in batch files, so just search for a good one. The other one who commented has written something that looks like it would fit.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem ... really idiot of my part, but I named the bat file as shutdown.bat ... so instead of actually shutting down the computer, it was calling itself again and again, that's why I got the loop problem :)